# In a table ,represent rows from two different arraylist one below the other based on some column value in java using jsp and jstl

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, arraylist, rows

I have two methods which gives me two arraylist which holds value of resultset given by two different sql query.Both the arraylsit has same number of columns and have same column name but with different number of rows.

Now I want to represent row retrieved from one arraylist below another if beam_current of one arraylist is equal to beam_current of another arraylsit where beam_current is column name of both resulset.I want to do this in jsp using jstl.

My jsp page code at present represent rows from one arraylsit and then rows from another arraylsit. The code for it is-

```
<table width = "300px" border = "1" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
  <th>beam_current</th>
  <th>beam_energy</th>
  <th>st2_vs2_bag1_rb</th>
  <th>st2_vs2_bag2_rb</th>
  <th>st2_vs2_bag3_rb</th>
  <th>st2_vs2_bag4_rb</th>
  <th>st2_vs2_bag5_rb</th>
  <th>st2_vs2_bag6_rb</th>
  <th>st2_vs2_bag7_rb</th>
  <th>st2_vs2_bag8_rb</th>
  <th>st2_vs2_bag9_rb</th>

</tr>

<c:forEach var="row" items="${ref.refarray_vac1(param.datepicker)}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${row.beam_current}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.beam_energy}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.st2_vs2_bag1_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.st2_vs2_bag2_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.st2_vs2_bag3_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.st2_vs2_bag4_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.st2_vs2_bag5_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.st2_vs2_bag6_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.st2_vs2_bag7_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.st2_vs2_bag8_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.st2_vs2_bag9_rb}"></c:out></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>

<c:forEach var="r" items="${ref.refernece(param.ref_logtime)}"> 
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${r.beam_current}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${r.beam_energy}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag1_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag2_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag3_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag4_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag5_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag6_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag7_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag8_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag9_rb}"></c:out></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>

</table>
```

**I know I have to use and tags of jstl to do comaprision of beam_current**.But how to implement it in my jsp page??

**EDIT-**

I have tried by using tag in such a way-

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${ref.refarray_vac1(param.datepicker)}">
<c:forEach var="r" items="${ref.refernece(param.ref_logtime)}"> 
<c:if test="${r.beam_current eq row.beam_current}">
<tr>

<td><c:out value="${row.beam_current}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.beam_energy}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.st2_vs2_bag1_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.st2_vs2_bag2_rb}"></c:out></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.st2_vs2_bag3_rb}"></c:out></td>
----------------------------------
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><c:out value="${r.beam_current}"></c:out></td>
 <td><c:out value="${r.beam_energy}"></c:out></td>
 <td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag1_rb}"></c:out></td>
 <td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag2_rb}"></c:out></td>
 <td><c:out value="${r.st2_vs2_bag3_rb}"></c:out></td>
 </tr>
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

**But now the problem is that when ever if condition is satisfied then double values are being displayed** i.e suppose in row.beam_current 10 rows are present corresponding to beam_current=50 and only one row is present in r.beam_current corresponding to 50 beam_current, then 20 rows for 50 beam_current are displayed.Why??

Comment: Because you typed two `<tr>` elements.